# How to describe a plane with two lines (multivariable calculus plane aproximation formula)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, plane-geometry

In one variable we have that the function approaches a line

$$f(x) = f(x_0) +f'(x_0)(x-a)$$

but in two variables we see that the function approaches a plane described by the two partial derivates:

$$z = z_0 + F_x(x-x_0) +F_y(y-yo)$$

First, how is this formula derived and second how is that $<F_x, F_y,1>$ is normal to the plane?

let:

$$L_1 = z_0+F_x(x-x_0)$$
$$L_2 =z_0 + F_y(y-y_0) $$

how would these two lines describe a plane? or how would you derive it by finding the normal vector of the plane

Comment: in one variable the way to derive it would be $$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \approx f'(x)$$ but that approach seems that does not work ot for two variables

Answer (score 1):

1. Excluding extreme circumstances such as the plane being perpendicular to the $xOy$ plane, a plane can be uniquely determined by $ax+by+cz+d (c\ne 0)$, thus given a point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ that the plane passes, we can use the formula $z(x,y) = z_0 + A(x-x_0) + B(y-y_0)$ to determine the plane.

   Now using the definition of *tangent*, $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} \Rightarrow A = F_x, B=F_y$.
2. The normal vector of the plane is simply $(F_x, F_y, 1)$ given the formula above.  BTW $L_1$ and $L_2$ are also planes, so it's quite hard to use these to deduce the normal vector.